# create custom marked degree for plotly windrose python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Is there a way to add additional degrees in windrose(default degrees marked as every 45° )? what I want to do is, mark degrees at every 22.5° instead of every 45°(0°,22.5°,45°,67.5° and so on).

I read the plotly windrose documentation, but couldn't able to find a suitable way to fix this.

[image]

code:

```
fig = px.bar_polar(df, r="Frequency", theta="wind_dir_Range",
                   color="Wind_Speed",
                   color_discrete_map={"0-10 km/h": "purple", "10-20 km/h": "cyan","20-30 km/h":"limegreen","30-40 km/h": "red"} 
  
                  )


fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have used alternate source of data... doesn't generate a good chart
- however it does show that you can adjust tick size using **dtick**

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.wind()
df = df.assign(Direction=np.random.uniform(0,360,len(df)))

fig = px.bar_polar(df, r="frequency", theta="Direction",
                   color="strength", template="plotly_dark",
                   color_discrete_sequence= px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r)
fig.update_layout(polar={"angularaxis":{"dtick":45/2}})
```